# Container Data Structure similar to std::vector and std::list

Tags: list, c++11, vector, containers, c++14

I am currently developing (at Design-Stage) a kinda small compiler which uses a custom IR. The problem I am having is to choose an efficient container data structure to contain all the instructions.

A basic block will contain ~10000 instructions and an instruction will be like ~250 Bytes big.

I thought about using a list because the compiler will have lots of complex transformations (ie. lots of random insertions/removals) so having a container data structure which does not invalidate iterators would be good. As it would keep the transformation algorithm simple and easy to follow.

On the other hand, it would be a lost of performance because of the known problem with cache misses and memory fragmentation. An std::vector would help here but I imagine it would be a pain to implement transformations with a vector.

So the questions is, if there is another data structure which has low memory fragmentation to reduce memory cache misses and does not invalidate iterators.
Or if I should ignore this and keep using a list.

Comment: I would recommend trying to get around the iterator invalidation problem

Answer (score 0):

Start with `using Container = std::vector<Instruction>`. `std::vector` is a pretty good default container. Once performance becomes an issue profile the program with a couple of different containers. You should be able to swap out the `Container` without needing much change in the rest of the code. I imagine some kind of array-list would be best, but you should probably check.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible as when I am randomly inserting and removing elements, iterators are invalidated, this is exactly the behavior I don't want. All transformations (also algorithms) have to be rewritten, this isn't good either.

Comment: @lled If you require stable iterators *and* random insertion and deletion there is no other way than a memory fragmented linked list. See if you can use indexes instead of iterators for the vector.